# How to automatically deploy docker to ec2 instance w/o ECS / Is it possible to SSH to an EC2 instance using the post build commands of a build script?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-ecs

I am using AWS ECS to automatically deploy my server in a docker container to my EC2 instance, the only problem is I have to use an elastic load balancer (ELB). This is a for a school project but it also uses a Telegram bot so I needed a HTTPS endpoint to receive updates from Telegram. An ELB is completely overkill for this and is also costing me more than I would like considering everything else is under the free tier that I am using. Does anyone know how to set up automatic deployment of a docker container to EC2 without an ELB/ECS OR does anyone know if it is possible to SSH to an EC2 instance during a build since that could possibly be a solution of how to run a deployment script on the instance automatically from the build. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You dont need ECS.to run Docker.  I have run Docker containers from an EC2 userdata script, so that is does a `docker run` command at launch.  Works great.